# Pass values to fields from Screen Manager screens issue

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am developing Android app. It has about 40 screens. I have the Barcode scanner, it should be in about 20 of these screens. I need to pass value from barcode scanner screen to other screens with TextInput. Currently, I added to one screen:

```
labScreen = "page3"
self.manager.get_screen(labScreen).ids.labBarcode.text = self.barcodeData
self.manager.current = labScreen
```

This code works, but it will require to create for every page new Barcode scanner screen + design and it is bad practice (concept), since I need to repeat myself. I want to use OOP (Object Oriented Programming), for example call/use it once and get data to TextInput fields from different screens. How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can create widget as a class (some layout for example) and put there your barcode scanner. So you will put instances of that class in every screen you need. Or you can create class of the screen with widgets if your screens are similar to each other. And you can define there classmethod (with @classmethod decorator) to change the text of the TextInput in all instances of that class. Give some more information about your screens and I'll try to give some example.

Comment: @Lothric

Thanks for the reply, but I will use my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have fixed it by using:

```
MDApp.get_running_app().barcodeValue = self.barcodeData
self.manager.current = MDApp.get_running_app().previousScreen
```

And set the previous screen as:

```
MDApp.get_running_app().previousScreen = self.manager.current
```

Now it works well. The issue is resolved.